# How do I set a password for individual folders?

Tags: password

I'm trying to find out how to set up passwords for individual folders. My computer has one User login so we all know the password to the computer. I want to be able to click a folder and it request a password to enter.

Hopefully without needing to download aplications or subscribe to things etc. All i want is a simple password protected box to pop up when I click a folder i have selected to protect.

This would mean my daughter would be un able to access my important files and accidentally delete or change anything. If anyone can provide some simple advice, that doesn't involve having my passwords or files backed up into an application that needs downloading, and has a straight forward answer to a simple request, it would be much appreciated.